# BungeeCord - Detected an authenticated player in offline mode

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, bungeecord

I've been trying for a few days how to detect if the account of a player is authenticated Mojang while he is in OfflineMode.

Why do I want to do that?

Currently, I have a basic management system that consists of checking if the player's nickname exists in the mojang database, if there is setOnlineMode set to true otherwise it is set to false.
  The system allows to display the skin of the player and his UUID but the problem is that if the player considered offline purchases a Premium account with the same pseudonym, he does not have his skin or his real UUID because the setOnlineMode is set to false to prevent the loss of its progress.
  My goal is to make a system that detects that an offline user has just logged in with an authenticated minecraft account so that the server can offer him an automatic transfer of his progress to his new authentic UUID.

I did some research is try as for example [here](https://github.com/SpigotMC/BungeeCord/blob/master/proxy/src/main/java/net/md_5/bungee/connection/InitialHandler.java#L391), i removed the onlinemode condition to allow checking if the player was authenticated then [here](https://github.com/SpigotMC/BungeeCord/blob/master/proxy/src/main/java/net/md_5/bungee/connection/InitialHandler.java#L446) I deleted the disconnect if the player was not valid. Which gave me a wonderful mistake.

```
13:13:31 [GRAVE] [Arbi13_] -> UpstreamBridge - encountered exception io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot get ID for packet class net.md_5.bungee.protocol.packet.SetCompression in phase GAME with direction TO_CLIENT
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:801)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:814)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:794)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1066)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:305)
    at net.md_5.bungee.netty.ChannelWrapper.write(ChannelWrapper.java:60)
    at net.md_5.bungee.UserConnection$1.sendPacket(UserConnection.java:148)
    at net.md_5.bungee.UserConnection.setCompressionThreshold(UserConnection.java:697)
    at net.md_5.bungee.connection.InitialHandler$6$1.run(InitialHandler.java:523)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:326)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot get ID for packet class net.md_5.bungee.protocol.packet.SetCompression in phase GAME with direction TO_CLIENT
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:399)
    at net.md_5.bungee.protocol.Protocol$DirectionData.getId(Protocol.java:462)
    at net.md_5.bungee.protocol.MinecraftEncoder.encode(MinecraftEncoder.java:23)
    at net.md_5.bungee.protocol.MinecraftEncoder.encode(MinecraftEncoder.java:9)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:107)
    ... 15 more
```

```
@Override
public void handle(LoginRequest loginRequest) throws Exception
{
    Preconditions.checkState( thisState == State.USERNAME, "Not expecting USERNAME" );
    this.loginRequest = loginRequest;

    if ( getName().contains( "." ) )
    {
        disconnect( bungee.getTranslation( "name_invalid" ) );
        return;
    }

    if ( getName().length() > 16 )
    {
        disconnect( bungee.getTranslation( "name_too_long" ) );
        return;
    }

    int limit = BungeeCord.getInstance().config.getPlayerLimit();
    if ( limit > 0 && bungee.getOnlineCount() > limit )
    {
        disconnect( bungee.getTranslation( "proxy_full" ) );
        return;
    }

    // If offline mode and they are already on, don't allow connect
    // We can just check by UUID here as names are based on UUID
    if ( !isOnlineMode() && bungee.getPlayer( getUniqueId() ) != null )
    {
        disconnect( bungee.getTranslation( "already_connected_proxy" ) );
        return;
    }

    Callback<PreLoginEvent> callback = new Callback<PreLoginEvent>()
    {

        @Override
        public void done(PreLoginEvent result, Throwable error)
        {
            if ( result.isCancelled() )
            {
                disconnect( result.getCancelReasonComponents() );
                return;
            }
            if ( ch.isClosed() )
            {
                return;
            }
            unsafe().sendPacket( request = EncryptionUtil.encryptRequest() );
            thisState = State.ENCRYPT;
        }
    };

    // fire pre login event
    bungee.getPluginManager().callEvent( new PreLoginEvent( InitialHandler.this, callback ) );
}

@Override
public void handle(final EncryptionResponse encryptResponse) throws Exception
{
    Preconditions.checkState( thisState == State.ENCRYPT, "Not expecting ENCRYPT" );

    SecretKey sharedKey = EncryptionUtil.getSecret( encryptResponse, request );
    BungeeCipher decrypt = EncryptionUtil.getCipher( false, sharedKey );
    ch.addBefore( PipelineUtils.FRAME_DECODER, PipelineUtils.DECRYPT_HANDLER, new CipherDecoder( decrypt ) );
    BungeeCipher encrypt = EncryptionUtil.getCipher( true, sharedKey );
    ch.addBefore( PipelineUtils.FRAME_PREPENDER, PipelineUtils.ENCRYPT_HANDLER, new CipherEncoder( encrypt ) );

    String encName = URLEncoder.encode( InitialHandler.this.getName(), "UTF-8" );

    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-1" );
    for ( byte[] bit : new byte[][]
    {
        request.getServerId().getBytes( "ISO_8859_1" ), sharedKey.getEncoded(), EncryptionUtil.keys.getPublic().getEncoded()
    } )
    {
        sha.update( bit );
    }
    String encodedHash = URLEncoder.encode( new BigInteger( sha.digest() ).toString( 16 ), "UTF-8" );

    String preventProxy = ( ( BungeeCord.getInstance().config.isPreventProxyConnections() ) ? "&ip=" + URLEncoder.encode( getAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress(), "UTF-8" ) : "" );
    String authURL = "https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/hasJoined?username=" + encName + "&serverId=" + encodedHash + preventProxy;

    Callback<String> handler = new Callback<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void done(String result, Throwable error)
        {
            if ( error == null )
            {
                LoginResult obj = BungeeCord.getInstance().gson.fromJson( result, LoginResult.class );
                if ( obj != null && obj.getId() != null )
                {
                    loginProfile = obj;
                    name = obj.getName();
                    uniqueId = Util.getUUID( obj.getId() );
                    authenticated = true;
                    finish();
                    return;


          }
            if(isOnlineMode()) {
                disconnect(bungee.getTranslation("offline_mode_player"));
                return;
            }

            finish();
            return;
        } else
        {
            disconnect( bungee.getTranslation( "mojang_fail" ) );
            bungee.getLogger().log( Level.SEVERE, "Error authenticating " + getName() + " with minecraft.net", error );
        }
    }
};

HttpClient.get( authURL, ch.getHandle().eventLoop(), handler );
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I always thought connecting with an official account to a offline server still loaded your name and skin correctly..

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible due to Minecraft not exchanging session details. I know servers who are running a second proxy with online mode enabled for the premium users to handle the session details leading to the same bukkit servers "behind".

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this: https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/fastlogin.14153/

I have not used it yet, but according to the reviews, it still works in the latest version.

Also, it's open source, you might be able to peek into the code and see how it's done.